# Set iframe innerHTML without loading page in it (with jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to set the contents of an iframe dynamically, when no pages were loaded before in the iframe.

I'm doing that :

```
iframe = $('<iframe id="thepage"></iframe>');

iframeHtml = 'iframeHtml';
$('body').append(iframe);

iframe
.contents()
.html(iframeHtml);
```

But it is not working, the html is still empty.

Comment: what is your console telling you?

Comment: nothing, it seems to work :) ([Document about:blank] from firebug)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

the best way to populate frame contents is `document.write`

```
var dstFrame = document.getElementById('yourFrameId');
var dstDoc = dstFrame.contentDocument || dstFrame.contentWindow.document;
dstDoc.write(yourHTML);
dstDoc.close()
```

UPD: that is

```
var iFrame = $('<iframe id="thepage"></iframe>');
$('body').append(iFrame);

var iFrameDoc = iFrame[0].contentDocument || iFrame[0].contentWindow.document;
iFrameDoc.write('<p>Some useful html</p>');
iFrameDoc.close();
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to avoid using `document.write`, which is generally not recommended any longer, you can get at the frame contents to add the content:

```
iframe = $('<iframe id="thepage"></iframe>')
iframeHtml = 'iframeHtml'
$('body').append(iframe)
iframe.contents().find('body').html(iframeHtml)
```

Answer (score 9):

Using JQuery, you can edit the iframe's attribute *srcdoc* by passing it the html as string:

```
$('#iframe_id').attr("srcdoc", htmlString);
```

Comment: This is pretty good, though it wouldn't load any script tags inside.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> iframe = $('<iframe id="thepage"></iframe>');
>
> iframeHtml = 'iframeHtml'; $('body').append(iframe);
>
> iframe .contents() .html(iframeHtml);
> ```

the reason it does not work is because `contents()` returns a `document` object and `html()` only works on `HTMLElemnt` objects, `html()` is basically a wrapper around `innerHTML` property and `document` does not have such property.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the jQuery `contents()` method.**

You can use the jQuery `contents()` method in combination with the `find()`, `val()` and `html()` methods to insert text or HTML inside an iframe body.

```
var EditFrame = $("#EditWindow").contents().find('body');  
var message = "Your message which needs to show in Iframe";
EditFrame.html(message);
```