# Body inside body

Tags: html

I have a question which I searched but could not find an answer yet.

I need to embed content of an html page within a html page. I basically want iframe functionality without using a separate page but just the content itself. 
I also need mother style sheet won't effect child style sheet in the same page.

so it will be like below and I need the magic_tag

```
<body style=1> mother page
```

`<magic_tag><body style=2> child page content </body></magic_tag>`
`</body>`

I wonder if this is possible or do I want something impossible

Comment: You can't do that. What is it you're trying to achieve? Why can't you use an iframe?

Comment: "*I also need mother style sheet won't effect child style sheet in the same page*" -- this is generally only possible with an iframe. As mentioned above: why not iframes? You may have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here -- what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: a PHP `include` or jQuery `load()` might do what you want, and more efficiently.

Comment: furthermore, "style=1" is no valid html-syntax.
If you need a completly different style for a specific area, you can add an class to that area, and make style-rules only for that specific class

Comment: Setting the iFrame source without an external doc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226307/set-iframe-innerhtml-without-loading-page-in-it-with-jquery

Comment: Looks like I need to give further input. I can't use Iframe (at least thats what I know) because I don't want two separate pages. Once all output is finished I wish to have single html file not multiple. 


I can't use separate style by classes as this is resultset coming from oracle sqlplus and there is no way to attend multiple classes to sqlplus html output. It comes as default without a class. resultsets are coming in grid table structure like <tr><td> and it is impossible to add class.

Comment: That is a good question, and I do not see why people have down voted it. It is very useful when you want to add a css file into an existing other one which might be in conflict of the former.

Answer (score 3):

You're approaching this the wrong way, try this ->

Don't give anything in the child "page" the same class or id as the parent "page"

http://jsfiddle.net/8pFMe/6/

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>Home </li>
                <li> Link </li>
                <li> Link2 </li>
                <li> Link3 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <ul>
                    <li>Sidebar Stuff</li>
                    <li>Link</li>
                    <li>Link2</li>
                    <li>Link3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="body">

                <div class="second-page">
                    <div class="second-container">
                         <div class="second-nav">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Home</li>
                                <li>Link</li>
                                <li>Link2</li>
                                <li>Link3</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="second-wrapper">
                            <div class="second-sidebar">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Sidebar Stuff</li>
                                    <li>Link</li>
                                    <li>Link2</li>
                                    <li>Link3</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="second-body">
                            <p> This looks similar to an iframe, but it's not an iframe.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.container{
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.nav li, .second-nav li{
    display:inline;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0 5px;
}

.sidebar{
    float:left;
    width:150px;
}

.body{
    width:340px;
    float:left;
    padding 5px
}

.second-page{
    border:1px solid #999;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I look for to sort the class problem. Thank you very much for sharing. 

Other problem is still valid as the page I need to embed is like here 

http://download.oracle.com/technology/products/manageability/database/active-reports/faq_simple_hj_build.html

it does not appear if I put it in the current body :(

Comment: I just saw this, did you get it figured out?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you *should* use `iframe`s anyway - most likely, you were having a communication problem with your supervisor. Maybe their degree is in managerial stuff or so, or it is in CS, but they don't know much of JavaScript. Maybe they don't even know what an `iframe` is. That is most likely, and that's why you got all those down-votes. It is simply hard to fathom any scenario where sane people (who aren't having a communication problem right there) would *really* want to do something like "do what `iframe` does --that is, *embed a page*--, but without using `iframe`". And you *are* saying you want to "*embed a page*", right? So, use `iframe`, there you go. I could say, in order to "do what iframe does, but without using it", use an `svg` tag, and then a `foreignObject` tag inside that, that is kind-of half way like an `iframe`. But again, it seems unlikely that this is what you *really* want.

But you deserve the benefit of the doubt. Maybe I'm wrong, and you *really* should embed the page using "copy and paste" - which is *a lot* more work than `iframe`. It could be about your page staying the same when the embedded page goes down or changes, who knows.

In that case, you would indeed get "body inside body" in your HTML, from copying the body you want to embed from the foreign page's HTML into your  own page's HTML. (you'll also have to copy some-but-not-all JavaScript, and some-but-not-all CSS, and all that can take quite some time.)

"body inside body" most likely isn't "well-formed", but it is OK to ignore that, because browsers (having to be backwards compatible) are *very very* robust when it comes to non-"well-formed"ness.

Then, when you want to ensure that the foreign CSS will apply to the embedded part, while the CSS of your page doesn't apply, the "body in body" quirk might just be a blessing in disguise. Namely, you could then prepend `body>body` to every path in the copied foreign CSS (except if it contains `body`, then replace `body` with `body>body`). And then, give the outer body a class which the foreign page is certain not to use (such as, use your own name), and prepend `body.coskan` everywhere in "your" CSS. This is very similar to what Jacques is suggesting.

Maybe a better idea (if indeed "creating an offline copy" of the foreign page is the issue) is this: Open the page you want to embed in a separate window/tab. Then, write some JavaScript, which uses `window.getComputedStyle` and `element.style`.*`lorem`*=*`ipsum`* in order to modify each dom node (within the part of the page you wish to embed) so that it has the style used in rendering (the computed style) as an inline style, so that all the CSS is "pushed into" the HTML (or DOM). Then, insert your modified HTML into your page. Most likely, someone has already written such a "CSS inline-ifyer" tool. The resulting HTML is "ugly", but who cares. It does what you want, and this method is a lot faster (development time) compared to the "Jacques method", and the embedded page really is static, unlike it would be, were you using `iframe`. ("static" meaning, if Oracle changes their page, it does not affect your page.)

On second thought, above "better idea" is really only/mostly suited if the embedded page doesn't have JavaScript; otherwise, better stay with "Jacques method". Yet another approach (if indeed, the to-be embedded part is non-interactive): make a screen shot, and include the image.

But maybe it's not "static" at all, and you actually need to communicate with the foreign page (e.g. query external database). Then, my initial "miscommunication assumption" is even more likely. Why on earth, in that case, not iframe? Well, you could do an `XMLHttpRequest`, and then dissect the result with JavaScript. It's then much more flexible than the iframe. But much more work, also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code